# How to show a post also on the user stream?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, x-facebook-platform

I developed a simple app on Faceobok that posts something on user wall. My issue is that the post isn't seen on wall stream, so he/she will probably never read it.
I developed this app in PHP with Facebook PHP-SDK and to post on user's wall i use: $facebook->api($userId .'/feed/','post',$attachment). 
Is it possible to show the post also on user' stream? (Maybe I forget to add a key/value in the attached array...)
Alternatively, is it possible to send a notification to the user in place of post or a notification linking to the wall post?
The post is personalized, so this is why I don't use a facebook page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting on the user stream is not possible (posts are visible just on user's friends stream).
Notification are not allowed, just for requests.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to send them an app-to-user request …? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

But keep in mind that you have to delete these requests yourself, once the user followed them.

Comment: thanks for your answer. A request doesn't seem to be a good solution for my app: I need to send 2-3 times per week a kind of feedback to the user, to inform him/her that there are interesting updates on specific topics. This is way my initial idea was to send a post on his/her wall or send a notification...